# Enabling context processors in app templates

Tags: python, django, templates

I have a few apps in a Django project with their own templates (i.e. `/project/app1/template`, `/project/app2/template` and so on).

However, template context processors (which are defined in the `settings.py` of the main app/project) are not available in those app templates.

I have to manually set the `context_instance` in order to enable context processors in child templates (otherwise context processors are missing from the templates):

```
from django.template import RequestContext

def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Here's my `settings.py`:

```
PACKAGE_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
BASE_DIR = PACKAGE_ROOT


TEMPLATES = [
    {
       "DIRS": [
            os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "templates"),
        ],
        "APP_DIRS": True,

        "OPTIONS": {
            ...
            "context_processors": [
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                ...
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

How do I access context processors in the app templates without manually injecting `context_instance` in each view function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't have anything at all to do with "app templates"; the behaviour is exactly the same no matter where your templates are located.

You always need a RequestContext if you want context processors to be run; apart from anything else, that's because they are passed the request object, so it needs to be present.

However there is a shortcut that creates that requestcontext, and that is the `render` function:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', {})
```

Note that this takes the request as the first argument.